# Why does NSArrayController require the module name in the class name (in IB) for Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift

I cannot remember a single time I've needed to give the program/module name when specifying a class name in interface builder except in this case, and also the book (Big Nerd 5th ed. p162) says I wouldn't need to do it for Obj-C, but I have to for Swift, so why?

Context: I'm specifying which class the NSArrayController will be dealing with.

[image: NSArrayController Class Name]

Comment: You have actually answered a question for me asking this! I have a project with spaces in the name (e.g. "My Project") and I couldn't get around how to add it to the calls name. It figures all I needed was the underscore: My_Project.MyClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift automatically creates impromptu namespaces for you, by (for example) prefixing your `Employee` class with your module name. (You don't have to care about this in your code, because since you're usually referring to `Employee` within that module, the compiler can understand your shorthand usage of `Employee`.) It can be handy to be explicit about this if your module defines the same symbol as another, for example `MyProject.Array` vs. `Swift.Array`.

Why the difference between languages? Because Objective-C simply does not do this namespacing, which is why everyone prefixes their Objective-C classes with two- and three-letter codes to avoid naming collisions.